# Use of iterrows() and arithmetic in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Indexing into an array in C is pretty easy and the brackets handle arithmetic nicely, thus allowing for the comparison of adjacent values. That's what I'd like to do in with iterrows() in Pandas, but I can't find a suitable example that shows how to do so. Consider the following:

```
         Year   Name        Winner  Count
432     1936    Alice       0.0      2
538     1937    Alice       1.0      2
6391    1985    Bob         1.0      2
6818    1989    Brad        0.0      2
```

Alice did not win a prize in 1936, but she did win one in 1937. I need to iterate over all of the rows, 1) check to see if the Year in row n immediately follows the Year in row n - 1, and 2) if so, did the subject win in the second year and not the first? Alice fits the bill, and I'd like to loop through the frame printing out her name and everyone else who meet the criteria.

I had started with . . .

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df['Year'] > df[df.Year - 1]:
```

And got, among other things, that the data type I had explicitly cast as an int (i.e., Year), is now being returned as a string. Is there a way to do this, or should I explore a different method?

Comment: check out `shift`. you don't want to use `iterrows` for this.

Comment: I will do that!

Comment: Clarifications: (1) This needs to be grouped by `Name` (i.e. subject)?  (2) Can a subject have more than 2 consecutive years?  If so, what is the inclusion rule?  (3) Can a subject have >2 years where all years are non-consecutive?

Comment: @andrew_reece -- Let me try to answer. 1) No grouping is required. The names just need to print to screen. I should have stated that. 2) Yes. The Years run from 1936 to 2015, a subject can appear anywhere in the series any number of times. If they appear In consecutive years, I'm interested in whether or not they lost in the first year, and won in the next. 3) Yes, a subject can appear in more than two years that are non consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some augmented sample data, to account for edge cases:

```
         Year   Name        Winner  Count
432     1936    Alice       0.0      2
538     1937    Alice       1.0      2
6390    1985    Bob         1.0      2
6817    1989    Brad        0.0      2
433     1997    Alice       0.0      2
539     1993    Alice       1.0      2
6391    1986    Bob         1.0      2
6818    1990    Brad        0.0      2
6819    1991    Brad        0.0      2
```

This approach sorts rows by `Name` and `Year`, then establishes whether a given year meets the criteria for inclusion (i.e., consecutive with the year before, and a win).
Then a simple `groupby()` finds the subjects who qualify.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.sort_values(['Name','Year'], inplace=True)

# eligible = consecutive year and won in that year
df['eligible'] = (df.Year.subtract(df.Year.shift()) == 1.) & (df.Winner)

# identify any person with at least one eligible year
df.groupby('Name').eligible.any())
```

Output:

```
Name
Alice     True
Bob       True
Brad     False
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! You've revealed not only how I would go about using .shift() properly, but also a .subtract() method, which may go a long way toward helping to solve the broader question of how I do arithmetic in this context to access df elements. Much appreciated!